# Sound playing during state restoration iOS

Tags: ios

I have an ios app that plays a sound when it opens the first time. I have added the state restoration code to my app delegate and set the restoration id in my view controllers, in my storyboard. My app seems to restore to the correct view controller but then jumps back to the second view controller and plays the sound again even though it is not opened to the view controller that initiates the sound. I tried to add a count to the sound so it would only play once but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I keep the sound from playing again? Thank you guys.

EDIT: I should mention the sound is being played through an AVPlayer in my initial view controller.

***After further inspection, If I bypass my first view controller everything works.

I then added a timer to my second view controller and presented my first view controller using the timer. In my animation block I use the completion handler to dismiss the first view controller and then everything seemed to work. The only issue now is that when the app is killed and reopened it presents the first view controller again, but at least when it dismisses it now it is actually where you left off instead of jumping back to the second view controller and only playing the sound from the first view controller. I might just keep it this way as it is a fun little animation, and will only play if the app is killed, but I just don't understand why it is doing this. I looked through all my connections, code and IB settings and there doesn't seem to be anything that jumps out at me. Has anyone else had any similar problems with restoration?

Answer (score 0):

Make that count variable static.
Declare it like:

```
static int count = 0;
  if(count == 0) {
   //then play the sound here
   //insert code here
  }
//the increment it here
count++;
```

Comment: I tried your idea but it didn't work. Thank you. I think I might be on the wrong track with a counter. I think it has something to do with state restoration and something else in my code. I appreciate the attempt though.